# pandas how to groupby inside a groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following data:

```
,dateTime,magnitude,occurrence,dateTime_s
1,2017-11-20 08:00:09.052260,12861,1,2017-11-20 08:00:09.000000
2,2017-11-20 08:00:09.052270,12868.12,1,2017-11-20 08:00:09.000000
3,2017-11-20 08:00:09.052282,12868.12,1,2017-11-20 08:00:09.000000
4,2017-11-20 08:00:09.052291,12867.5,2,2017-11-20 08:00:09.000000
5,2017-11-20 08:00:09.052315,12867.5,4,2017-11-20 08:00:09.000000
6,2017-11-20 08:00:09.052315,12867,1,2017-11-20 08:00:09.000000
7,2017-11-20 08:00:09.052315,12865.5,1,2017-11-20 08:00:09.000000
8,2017-11-20 08:00:09.052315,12865.89,1,2017-11-20 08:00:09.000000
9,2017-11-20 08:00:12.064744,12867.5,1,2017-11-20 08:00:12.000000
10,2017-11-20 08:00:12.131555,12868.5,2,2017-11-20 08:00:12.000000
11,2017-11-20 08:00:12.333511,12868.5,4,2017-11-20 08:00:12.000000
12,2017-11-20 08:00:12.333511,12869.95,2,2017-11-20 08:00:12.000000
13,2017-11-20 08:00:12.341516,12869.5,1,2017-11-20 08:00:12.000000
14,2017-11-20 08:00:12.343538,12868.5,1,2017-11-20 08:00:12.000000
15,2017-11-20 08:00:12.343538,12868.17,5,2017-11-20 08:00:12.000000
16,2017-11-20 08:00:12.343538,12867.5,2,2017-11-20 08:00:12.000000
17,2017-11-20 08:00:14.148704,12882.5,1,2017-11-20 08:00:14.000000
18,2017-11-20 08:00:14.148748,12882.5,1,2017-11-20 08:00:14.000000
19,2017-11-20 08:00:14.218977,12883.66,1,2017-11-20 08:00:14.000000
20,2017-11-20 08:00:14.218977,12883.5,1,2017-11-20 08:00:14.000000
21,2017-11-20 08:00:14.385283,12882.09,1,2017-11-20 08:00:14.000000
22,2017-11-20 08:00:14.388518,12881.5,1,2017-11-20 08:00:14.000000
23,2017-11-20 08:00:14.577002,12882.5,1,2017-11-20 08:00:14.000000
```

And I am using the following code to aggregate it by time (as it's milis and I need it by seconds.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Data/test.csv')
print(df.head(30))

groups = df.groupby('dateTime_s')
df_grouped = (groups.agg({
            'magnitude': np.mean,
            'occurrence': np.sum,
            }))
print(df_grouped.head())
```

The result is good:

```
                               magnitude  occurrence
dateTime_s                                          
2017-11-20 08:00:09.000000  12866.328750          12
2017-11-20 08:00:12.000000  12868.515000          18
2017-11-20 08:00:14.000000  12882.607143           7
```

But for my research I need to add the most frequent magnitude and it's occurrence. How can I groupby (inside current groupby) and calculate the magnitude with the most frequency and to display both the magnitude and frequency?

I am looking for a result like this:

```
                    groupby magnitude   
    dateTime_s      magnitude   occurrence  max sum
2017-11-20  08:00:09.000000     12866.32875 12  12867.5 6
2017-11-20  08:00:12.000000     12868.515   18  12868.5 7
2017-11-20  08:00:14.000000     12882.607143    7   12882.5 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need custom function for `sum` of `occurrence` values by top `magnitude` values:

```
groups = df.groupby('dateTime_s')
df_grouped = (groups.agg({
            'magnitude': np.mean,
            'occurrence': np.sum,
            })) 
#print (df_grouped)

def f(x):
    a = x['magnitude'].value_counts().index[0]
    b = x.loc[x['magnitude'] == a, 'occurrence'].sum()
    return pd.Series([a,b],['max magn','freq oc'])

df_grouped1 = groups.apply(f)
#print (df_grouped1)


df = pd.concat([df_grouped, df_grouped1], axis=1)
print (df)
                        magnitude  occurrence  max magn  freq oc
dateTime_s                                                      
2017-11-20 08:00:09  12866.328750          12   12867.5      6.0
2017-11-20 08:00:12  12868.515000          18   12868.5      7.0
2017-11-20 08:00:14  12882.607143           7   12882.5      3.0
```

Or only custom function:

```
groups = df.groupby('dateTime_s')

def f(x):
    a = x['magnitude'].value_counts().index[0]
    b = x.loc[x['magnitude'] == a, 'occurrence'].sum()
    c = x['magnitude'].mean()
    d = x['occurrence'].sum()
    return pd.Series([a,b,c,d],['max magn','freq oc', 'mean', 'sum'])

df_grouped1 = groups.apply(f)
print (df_grouped1)

                     max magn  freq oc          mean   sum
dateTime_s                                                
2017-11-20 08:00:09   12867.5      6.0  12866.328750  12.0
2017-11-20 08:00:12   12868.5      7.0  12868.515000  18.0
2017-11-20 08:00:14   12882.5      3.0  12882.607143   7.0
```

Comment: thanks. but I need the sum for the freq, so for 12867.5 I need to get 6 as it happened 2 and 4 (so count does show 2 which is correct) but I need the sum.

Comment: Also `Multiindex` in columns was removed, there are only simply columns names. Is it OK?

Comment: well this does solve the problem but as usually in pandas, since i have already my code set with groupby and lambdas for other calculations. I will have to rewrite it or pls tell me there is a way to keep it in the lambda format as before??? or i can concat the 2 df together?

Comment: I remove lambdas functions, because in pandas by aggregate is not possible working with 2 columns together, what need for `freq oc`. So need `apply`.